# How to read multiple lines of responce with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am working on a sudoku bot with some sudoku API, and I want the user to type something like this:

```
>sudoku_solve
2........
.....62..
..1....7.
..6..8...
3...9...7
...6..4..
.4....8..
..52.....
........3
```

So first will be the command, and then the sudoku table itself. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Of course it is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I am new to discord.py so my only idea was to use the *parameter, but it returns only first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the args provided.

```py
@bot.command()
async def sudoko_solve(ctx, *, args):
    await ctx.send(args)
```

This passes all the words after the invoking command as a string.

References:-

- [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html?highlight=commands)
- [keyword args](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it

```
@bot.command()
async def sudoku_solve(ctx):
    message = ctx.message.content
    message_slice = message[13:]
    await ctx.send(message_slice)
```

I just removed first 13 letters of the message.